# SQLException "Column 'java.lang.Integer' not found" when reading from a ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I am trying to do some basic ResultSet to JSONArray conversion.

The code in question is the following:

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

String column_name = rsmd.getColumnClassName(1);

if(rsmd.getColumType(i) == java.sql.Types.Integer) {
    obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));
}
```

When I publish the code to the web-server and hit the page, it throws the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'java.lang.Integer' not found.
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:937)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:872)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2571)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ResultSetWrapper.getInt(ResultSetWrapper.java:482)
at com.pododdle.util.ToJSON.toJSONArray(ToJSON.java:58)
atcom.pododdle.restful.resources.CategoryResource.returnCategories(CategoryResource.java:44)
```

Which is kinda crazy since it is complaining it can't find java.lang.Integer - a core java class!!!!

It also fails when I use the string equivalent and says it can't find java.lang.String either.

Please help. I am starting to lose my mind.

PS I don't know if this is relevant, but Maven was not automatically updating any new dependencies I wanted, so I added them manually.  I don't know if this points to a greater malady in my installation - which is pretty fresh - only got eclipse et al installed yesterday on my new machine.

Comment: Please pay attention to the error message. It does not say that Java does not find the class `java.lang.Integer`, but that SQL can’t find the column `java.lang.Integer`.

Comment: adding on, for updating the maven dependencies, please do a "mvn clean install" at the location of your pom file.

Comment: This is caused by a typographical error, and should be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `rsmd.getColumnClassName(1)` as a column name. Now obviously the method [`ResultSetMetaData.getColumnClassName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnClassName(int)) returns the *name of the class* for that column. In your case, this column stores an integer value, so `java.lang.Integer` is returned. Try to use [`ResultSetMetaData.getColumnName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnName(int)) instead to get the *name* of the column.

Comment: Thanks a million - i was blind. Very Stupid.

Comment: @TomO'Brien You’re welcome. If this answer was useful, please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.